# ¿Como extraer las propiedades de una función con nombre en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola comunidad espero que me puedan ayudar con este problema de funciones de javascript ya que no soy muy avanzado en ello.

Tengo una función con nombre llamada detalle_subgrid a la que quiero acceder a sus propiedades como por ejemplo a valores_detalle y mostrar el contenido en un console.log().
¿Alguien sabe como poder acceder a ellas?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Aquí coloco mi código.

```js
var detalle_subgrid = function(index, parentElement, gridElement, record) {

    var valores_detalle;
    var datafields_detalle = new Array();
    var columns_detalle = new Array();
    var id = $("#gvDatos").jqxGrid('getrowdata', index)['id_Perona'];
    var grid = $($(parentElement).children()[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frm¨Persona.aspx/ListarPersona",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_persona:"' + id + '"}',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {

            
        if (data != '') {
        
                valores_detalle = data.d;
                valores_detalle = JSON.parse(valores_detalle);
                console.log(valores_detalle);
                for (var x in valores_detalle[0]) {
                    datafields_detalle.push({ name: x });
                    columns_detalle.push({ text: x, datafield: x, align: 'center', minwidth:100 });
                   
                }

            }

            var nestedGridSource =
            {

                datatype: 'json',
                datafields: datafields_detalle,
                localdata: valores_detalle, //data.d
                async: false
            };

            var nestedGridAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(nestedGridSource);
           
            if (grid != null) {
                grid.jqxGrid({
                source: nestedGridAdapter,
                width: '94%',
                height: 220,
                columnsresize: true,
                autoheight: false,
                autorowheight: false,
                altrows: true,
                columns: columns_detalle
                   
                });
            }
           
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
            console.log(error.responseText);
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
            alert(error.respose.Text);
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}


// Aqui afuera de la funcion trato de acceder a sus propiedades pero no me muestra el resultado que contiene.

function obtener_datos(){
...
  console.log(detalle_subgrid.valores_detalle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar utilizando la funcion each

ejemplo:

```
$.each( data.d, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

ó

```
for each (var value in data.d) {
   alert( value );
}
```